# image is not appearing with email

Tags: html, image, email

I am sending a html table with an image of google map.for mozilla Thunderbird image is appearing without any problem.but for gamil and yahoo mail image is not appearing.even a broken image.is there any reason for that? here is the image tag I attached to the table

```
<image src = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?path='+startCity+'|'+dueTodrawPath+endCity+'&size=500x200&maptype=roadmap&sensor=true" />'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

shouldn't it be `<img src="" />`

Answer (score 1):

`<image>` is not a valid tag, you should be using `<img>`